# How to proper read ADC by ULP while ESP32 wake up

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I am going to continously measure ADC data with ULP. Periodically I wake up ESP32 to do some stuff. When I analyse data received from ADC I found that there is about 100 ms of time where ADC return 0xfff while wake up ESP32 core (ULP work continously)
I am using Olimex ESP32-DevKit-LiPo, PlatformIO with Hulp library.

With sample code (below), which measure ADC and after about 400 measurements it wakes ESP32,  I always receive 4095 for about 100 ms and then ADC values return to measured values. In example code there is ULP period set to 4 ms, and there are 24 0xfff results.
Is it ESP32 bug (or feature) or what am I doing wrong (and how could it be fixed?)

below some results with format **sample number** --> **ADC result**,

> 0 --> 1891,  1 --> 1893,  2 --> 1890,  3 --> 1882,  4 --> 1881,  5 --> 1883,
> . . . . . .

> 399 --> 1893,  400 --> 1887,  401 --> 1889,   402 --> 1891,  403 --> 1899,
> **404 --> 4095,  405 --> 4095,  406 --> 4095,  407 --> 4095, 408 --> 4095,  409 -->
> 4095,  410 --> 4095,  411 --> 4095,  412 --> 4095,  413 --> 4095,
>
> 414 --> 4095,  415 --> 4095,  416 --> 4095,  417 --> 4095,  418 -->
> 4095,  419 --> 4095, 420 --> 4095,  421 --> 4095,  422 --> 4095,  423
> --> 4095,  424 --> 4095,  425 --> 4095,   426 --> 4095,  427 --> 4095,**  428 --> 1904,  429 --> 1893,  430 --> 1890,  431 --> 1883, 432 -->
> 1879,  433 --> 1879,  434 --> 1877,  435 --> 1873,  436 --> 1881,  437
> --> 1894,   438 --> 1904,  439 --> 1904,  440 --> 1903,  441 --> 1904,  442 --> 1905,  443 --> 1909, 444 --> 1910,  445 --> 1914,

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "hulp_arduino.h"

#define bufor_lnght 400
#define bufor_lnght_max bufor_lnght + 400

typedef union
{
  uint16_t d_ADC[bufor_lnght + 200];
  uint8_t d_ADC_8[(bufor_lnght + 200) * 2];

} dane_pom_X;

struct paczka_ws
{
  uint16_t meas_id;
  dane_pom_X dane;
};

paczka_ws dane_ADC_ws;

#define ULP_WAKEUP_INTERVAL_MS (4)

#define ADC_IN GPIO_NUM_34

RTC_DATA_ATTR struct
{
  ulp_var_t ULP_meas_cntr;
  ulp_var_t ULP_buf_RTC_to_RAM;
  ulp_var_t ULP_ADC_result[bufor_lnght_max];
} ulp_vars;

void ulp_init()
{
  enum
  {
    LBL_MEAS_ADC,
    LBL_WAKEUP_TRIGGERED,
    LBL_HALT,
  };

  const ulp_insn_t program[] = {
      // Set a register to 0 for use with I_GET and I_PUT
      I_MOVI(R3, 0),

      I_GET(R0, R3, ulp_vars.ULP_meas_cntr),
      I_SUBI(R0, R0, bufor_lnght_max),
      M_BXF(LBL_MEAS_ADC),

      I_MOVI(R0, bufor_lnght_max - 1),
      I_PUT(R0, R3, ulp_vars.ULP_meas_cntr),

      M_LABEL(LBL_MEAS_ADC),

      I_ANALOG_READ(R0, ADC_IN),

      I_GET(R1, R3, ulp_vars.ULP_meas_cntr), 

      I_PUT(R0, R1, ulp_vars.ULP_ADC_result),
      I_ADDI(R1, R1, 1),                     
      I_PUT(R1, R3, ulp_vars.ULP_meas_cntr),

      I_GET(R0, R3, ulp_vars.ULP_meas_cntr),
      I_SUBI(R0, R0, bufor_lnght + 2),
      M_BXZ(LBL_WAKEUP_TRIGGERED),

      M_BX(LBL_HALT),

      M_LABEL(LBL_WAKEUP_TRIGGERED),

      I_MOVI(R0, 1),
      I_PUT(R0, R3, ulp_vars.ULP_buf_RTC_to_RAM),

      M_WAKE_WHEN_READY(),

      M_LABEL(LBL_HALT),

      I_HALT(),
  };

  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(hulp_configure_analog_pin(ADC_IN, ADC_ATTEN_DB_11, ADC_WIDTH_BIT_12));

  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(hulp_ulp_load(program, sizeof(program), 1000UL * ULP_WAKEUP_INTERVAL_MS, 0));
  ESP_ERROR_CHECK(hulp_ulp_run(0));
}

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  if (hulp_is_deep_sleep_wakeup())
  {
    if (ulp_vars.ULP_buf_RTC_to_RAM.val == 1)
    {
      for (uint16_t i = 0; i < bufor_lnght + 100; i++)
      {
        dane_ADC_ws.dane.d_ADC[i] = ulp_vars.ULP_ADC_result[i].val;
      }
      ulp_vars.ULP_buf_RTC_to_RAM.val = 0;

      for (uint16_t i = 0; i < bufor_lnght + 100; i++)
      {
        Serial.print(i);
        Serial.print(" --> ");
        Serial.print(dane_ADC_ws.dane.d_ADC[i]);
        Serial.print(",  ");
        if (i % 6 == 5)
        {
          Serial.println();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ulp_init();
    ulp_vars.ULP_meas_cntr.val = 0;
    ulp_vars.ULP_buf_RTC_to_RAM.val = 0;
  }
  Serial.println("Sleeping...");

  esp_sleep_enable_timer_wakeup(10000000);
  esp_deep_sleep_disable_rom_logging();
  esp_sleep_enable_ulp_wakeup();
  esp_deep_sleep_start();
}

void loop()
{
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: Similar ESP-IDF code works without problem. it looks like it is Arduino or HULP problem